# htaccess - Redirect all PDF files excluding PDFs in specified folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, file-type

We have a lot of PDFs on our site that aren't quite done yet, but the links to them are scattered throughout our site. So we want an htaccess rule that redirects all links to PDF files to a landing page, while also allowing the links to work normally if the PDFs are within certain directories.

So if all PDFs in the /xyz/ directory are done, we'd like the redirect rule to exclude all PDFs in the /xyz/ directory, while all other PDF links go to the landing page.

Here's kind of what I mean even though it doesn't work yet:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xyz/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.pdf$ /landing-page.php [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check this rule on the top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^xyz/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.pdf$ /landing-page.php [R=301,L]
```

It's redirect all non exists PDF files to landing-page.php (excludes xyz folder).